# Running a simple python app on Windows 7 embedded gives an "Entry point not found error" and an "Error loading dll"

Tags: python, dll, entrypointnotfoundexcept, windows-7-embedded

I am trying to run a simple small app I made in python on a device running Windows 7 embedded (2GB RAM, Intel Atom).
I am creating an exe using **pyinstaller** (dev version, for supporting Python 3.6)

When I run the exe I get the following error:

```
the procedure entry point ucrtbase.terminate api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll
```

**Followed by this error:**

```
"Error loading Python DLL:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\_MEI57202\python36.dll (error code 127)"
```

I used **pyinstaller** as follows: `pyinstaller -w -F`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Please let me know if you need to see the script, it's a simple one.

> Edit: Installing *KB2999226* from Microsoft did make the error's
>   disappear but now the script will silently not execute.

Any ideas?

> Final Edit: Installing the above update solved it. The problem with
>   not executing was I used a 64Bit FFMPEG on a 32bit OS. Closing with
>   solution

Comment: I read a bit more and found a microsoft fix _Universal CRT Update KB2999226_ as seen here: [link]https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows 
I do not know, though, if I can install it on Windows 7 embedded

Answer (score 0):

Installing KB2999226 from MS solved it